# azure logic apps, get the key of a json response

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic apps that sends a request and expect a response. the response has an important value, but it comes as a key, and I need to store it in a variable. how can I get this key and store as a value.

eg: `{"subscriptions": {"ABC": "true"}}` -> I need to get `"ABC"` and store it in a variable, something like ->`initialize variable -> var_abc="ABC"`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way is to use Javascript code component as it is part of Azure Logic Apps now. This is very powerful and it allows playing with data and objects with javascripts.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code

Comment: Hi delpha, as you have found the best way, please mark yourself answer as "accepted", this can be beneficial to other community members, thanks~

Comment: How about sharing your solution to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action and use your response json data as the content of this action. Then click "Use sample payload to generate schema" at the bottom of this action and input your json to generate the schema.

[image]

Now you can use "[initialize variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values#initialize-variable)" action to initialize a variable and set the value with the data of "ABC"
[image]

Comment: thnks. it got actually a lot more complicated and i needed a programming language to do what I wanted to do at the end. using javascript and its functionalities was the best solution